# Patterns for preg_match

Tags: preg_match, php

Если вы поняли заголовок, значит ура) меня интересует конструкция паттернов для регулярного выраженя preg_match. Желательно весь мануал по поводу что такое **i** **u** и т.д. короче говоря кто знает, тот меня понял. ссылки на темы, мануалы и прочее... язык желательно русский и английский) ну и немецкий тоже потяну)

P.S. Правда, перед самим собой стыдно. А я то самоучка, хочется больше)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Синтаксис паттернов [в доках](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) на оффсайте PHP.
На русском :)

Comment: аха) глуп я) как говорится зажрался))) спасибо)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Вообще в инете много инфы по preg-регуляркам. Но на офф-сайте наиболее полная и систематизированная документация.